# Prevent instantiation of MongoDB data model outside of current assembly or prevent misuse

Tags: c#, mongodb, factory, instantiation, internal

Ive got a mongo database set up and if its designed to use strongly typed objects:

```
 public class Message : IDatabaseObject
    {

        [DataMember]
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string MessageBody { get; set; }
}
```

The class and all properties need to be public for MongoDB to use it as an object

I was about to make a factory to create a new instance as opposed to creating an instance of Message (duplicating code) each time but then I realised there would be more than one way to create a Message.

Is there a way to prevent direct instantiation of the data object outside of the assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a `private` or `internal` property for serialization in mongo, but you can make the **setter of property** `private` or `internal` (mongo c# driver will take care of private setters for serializing and deserializing).

Make the **constructor** and **setters** internal or private (based on your use-case)

```
public class Message
{
    [DataMember]
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; internal set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string MessageBody { get; internal set; }

    internal Message() { }
}

public static class MessageFactory
{
    public static Message Create()
    {
        return new Message();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expose a public factory method like `DatabaseObjectFactory.Create<Message>()` or `Message.Create()`, while keeping the constructor `internal` or even `private`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is enough that during compile time you can't instanciate the class, Fody might be what you want. Specificially `Publicize.Fody`.

It allows you to write your class as `internal`. Compile it. Then have it run as a `public` class.